# Magento 2 bug when saving configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm having a weird issue with Magento 2 and configurable products.

I am absolutely not able to create configurable products on my local server. When I try to save a configurable product, I get a SQL warning and it becomes a simple one.
I was about to give up, but same operation worked when I installed Magento 2 on my web hosting provider.

Everything is ok since I created a new user with admin capabilities.
With my account, there is no problem with configurable products, but with his account it's the same as previously described on my local server:
- he cannot create configurable products (sql error + the product becomes simple)
- when he edits and save configurable products that I have previously created, the products lose their name, custom attributes, become inactive and not visible individually.

I have searched for a long while on forums but couldn't find answers to this problem.
Did anyone get the same bug with configurable products and Magento 2?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the clue! Weird in fact...

I was about to delete the second user who had problems to create and edit configurable products when I realized that his back-end was in French while mine was in English. On my local install my interface is also in French.

When set to English, no more problems with configurable products!
I use this package for French translation: https://github.com/lalbert/magento2-fr_fr

Does anyone encountered a similar issue when the back-end is localized?